# Is 'photocount' parameter deprecated?

Tags: foursquare

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?
```

I see that `photo count` has been lost in space...

Does `photo count` 
will not return  from `stats` anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, but the explore endpoint still returns the count of photos, as you can see here.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore.html#req=venues/explore%3Fnear%3D10009

Make sure to always pass a version string and you should never see backwards-incompatible JSON changes: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/versioning

Comment: They renamed 'photocount' to 'photos:{count:}'